# Nginx config for unleash not working after reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a very thin app in a server and I just set up [unleash](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-docker) (feature flag management tool) on it (with docker).
So I just opened the port 4242 in both the host and the container machine (docker-compose segment bellow).

```
services:

  custom-unleash:
    container_name: custom_unleash
    image: unleashorg/unleash-server:latest
    command: docker-entrypoint.sh /bin/sh -c 'node index.js'
    ports:
    - "4242:4242"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=foo
      - DATABASE_NAME=bar
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=foo
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=bar
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

then I added the following configuration to my nginx configs,

```
   location /unleash {
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:4242;
       access_log /var/log/nginx/unleash-access.log  main;
   }
```

But when I simply enter `http://SERVER_IP:4242/` in my browser the unleash login page appears; but when I want to access unleash panel via `https://SERVER_DNS/unleash` there will be a blank page.
I think it's because the browser tries to get `static/index.1f5d6bc3.js` file from `https://SERVER_DNS/`, (i.e. GET `https://SERVER_DNS/static/index.1f5d6bc3.js`).
but in the first scenario when I enter `http://SERVER_IP:4242/` the browser tries to GET the file from `http://SERVER_IP:4242/static/index.1f5d6bc3.js` which will work because the unleash server will serve it.

Why this happens? how can I prevent the unleash server to send `https://SERVER_DNS/static/index.1f5d6bc3.js` file while it does not exists in my host server? is there something wrong with my nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the nginx configuration but since you're deploying under a subpath maybe you need to add the environment variable `UNLEASH_URL` as specified in the docs https://docs.getunleash.io/reference/deploy/configuring-unleash#unleash-url

If that doesn't help, let me know and I'll get help from someone else from the team.